# Preventing main page being a directory

Tags: git, hosting, html

This is my first time working on pushing files into a hosting service and creating a website. I have a set of folders and one php file I want as the homepage. I'm relatively new to git. I was able to push and commit the files to the Pagoda server and get the webpage to working. The problem is is that when I go to the page a directory is shown displaying all of my files. Would I need to use htaccess to have the php file displayed on the page instead of the directory in order or do I do this through git. I'm really unsure how to go about this.

Comment: This is kind of a mixture of topics. You sound like you have the git aspect all cleared up, and this might be related simply to your web server settings and project structure. Is your top level php filed named `index.php` ?

Comment: No I completely forgot about that. If in the group of files I create a file named index.php, should I expect the web server to automatically direct me to index.php instead of the web directory?

Comment: index.* is usually the web server default for the index of a specific directory. That will be the page that is hit if you were to go to something like "/" or "/subdir/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have index.php/index.html among your files to prevent all of your files being seen.